# How do I concisely update a highly nested object model using swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I am writing a function which will dig into the deepest level of a object hierarchy and update a particular value. For reference, this is how messy a regular iteration turned out to be:

```
func selectedStateUpdated(data: MyObject, tabId: String, rowId: String){
    for currIndex in 0..<self.model.data[0].data[0].filters.count{
        if(self.model.data[0].data[0].filters[currIndex].headerName == data.headerName){
            for tabIdx in 0..<model.data[0].data[0].filters[currIndex].data.count {
                if(self.model.data[0].data[0].filters[currIndex].data[tabIdx].id == tabId){
                    for rowItemIdx in 0..<self.model.data[0].data[0].filters[currIndex].data[tabIdx].data.count {
                        if(self.model.data[0].data[0].filters[currIndex].data[tabIdx].data[rowItemIdx].id == rowId){
                            self.model.data[0].data[0].filters[currIndex].data[tabIdx].data[rowItemIdx].isSelected.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to dig this deep into my data model and update a particular attribute? I am trying to update the `model` object which resides in the class of this function as a global object. Given that iterable objects in my object model are immutable in for-loops, is there a better way of approaching this while making sure I iterated into the proper

Comment: Don't write `0..<array.count`. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

Answer (score 0):

At its core, this is a data structure problem. You're doing a linear search through all your data to find something with a specific `headerName`, `tabId`, `rowId`. It's complicated, messy and slow (`O(headerCount * tabCount * rowCount)`!)

If dictionaries were used, this could just be:

```
self.model.data[0].data[0]
    .filters[headerName]
    .data[tabId]
    .data[rowId]
    .isSelected
    .toggle()
```

If the arrays must stay, then you can clean this up a lot by extracting common parts to named local variables. Inverting the `if` statements (in this case, into `guard` statements`) also saves a ton on nesting:

```
func selectedStateUpdated(headerName: String, tabId: String, rowId: String){
    let data = self.model.data[0].data[0] // TODO: name me better

    for currIndex in 0..<data.filters.count {
        let filter = data.filters[currIndex]
        guard filter.headerName == headerName else { return }

        for tabIdx in 0..<filter.data.count {
            let tab = filter.data[tabIdx]
            guard tab.id == tabId else { continue }

            for rowItemIdx in 0..< tab.data.count {
                let rowItem = tab.data[rowItemIdx]
                guard rowItem.id == rowId else { continue }

                self.model.data[0].data[0]
                    .filters[currIndex]
                    .data[tabIdx]
                    .data[rowItemIdx]
                    .isSelected
                    .toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It could be further improved by using `zip` to get indices and items in one shot:

```
func selectedStateUpdated(headerName: String, tabId: String, rowId: String){
    let data = self.model.data[0].data[0] // TODO: name me better

    for (currIndex, filter) in zip(data.filters.indices, data.filters) {
        guard filter.headerName == headerName else { return }

        for (tabIdx, tab) in zip(filter.data.indices, filter.data) {
            guard tab.id == tabId else { continue }

            for (rowItemIdx, rowItem) in zip(tab.data.indices, tab.data) {
                guard rowItem.id == rowId else { continue }

                self.model.data[0].data[0]
                    .filters[currIndex]
                    .data[tabIdx]
                    .data[rowItemIdx]
                    .isSelected
                    .toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing when you say ".id == tabId" is a filter function. This code was quite messy. But i think i managed to figure it out:

```
func selectedStateUpdated(data: [MyObject], tabId: String, rowId: String) {

    let filteredResult = self.model.data[0].data[0].filters
        .filter({$0.headerName == data.headerName &&
            $0.data.filter({$0.id == tabId}) &&
            $0.data.filter({$0.id == tabId &&
                $0.data.filter({$0.id == rowId})
            })
        })

    if filteredResult.count > 0 {
        filteredResult.first!.isSelected.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Would this approach allow me to efficiently set all `isSelected` values to false also?

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `first!` on the last row and loop that through as well